# k-NN of points in R^d (defining the Joint Space)

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, information-theory

My question is related to estimate mutual information (in Python), using many large vectors from two sets.
I am using **k-NN (applying ANN)** to use Kraskov et. al definition. I know there are some repos out there that use **cKDTree**. Nevertheless, they always have examples using points from R^1. So, I tried to extend the definition but I couldn't define the **joint space** (for the joint entropy), because I don't know how to define it when the points are in R^d.

**More in details:**

They usually have two sets of points in R^1, let's say 1000 elements each set, e.g. `x=[[3.1], [4.2], ..., [1.0]]` and `y=[[0.1], [0.3], ..., [1.2]]`, when they compute the **joint space** a new object is created `js=[[3.1, 0.1], [4.2, 0.3], ..., [1.0, 1.2]]`. Then this space is used to create the index (cKDTree), the queries are done using those new points:

```
tree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(js)
dvec = [tree.query(point, k+1, p=float('inf'))[0][k] for point in js]
```

My questions are:

**1. In that example of R^1 are they computing the distance of each point from x and y index-respective?** i.e taking `js[0]` the distance between 3.1 and 0.1? I need the dvec, because as far as I understand, I require dvec to compute *avgdigamma*

and more important:

**2. How do I compose js when the points are from R^d?** I have tried: `js=[[[3.1, ..., ], [0.1, ..., ]], [[4.2, ..., ], [0.3, ..., ]], ..., [[1.0, ..., ], [1.2, ..., ]]]` but `cKDTree` complains saying that *data must be 2 dimensions*. **Should I try doing something like this**: `js=[[3.1, ..., 0.1, ..., ], [4.2, ..., 0.3, ..., ], ..., [1.0, ..., 1.2, ..., ]]` that would be considered a **joint space**, and the *dvec* would be the distance of 3.1, ..., and 0.1, ...,?

Please let me know if I need to be more clear

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: 1. If x and y are 1-dimensional variables, then you are computing k-nearest neighbour distances in the 2-dimensional plane as a proxy for entropy in the joint space. In other words, you are not computing differences between an x and a y value but distances between two points (a sample and it k-th neighbour), each having an x and y value. 2. If your data is d-dimensional, you should pass a N samples (rows) by d-dimensions (columns) array to KDTree/cKDTree.

Comment: Thanks Paul I am more clear with 1. About 2, surely I made a mistake explaining, but with 2 I meant having vectors from two spaces which both are d-dimensional, so my data should be N samples (rows) by (d+d)-dimensions (columns), that is what you meant?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: FYI, if you are looking for a reference implementation to compare your code against, I have repository for entropy estimators of continuous distributions. The KSG estimator is implemented [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/entropy_estimators/blob/master/entropy_estimators/continuous.py#L231).

Comment: I do really appreciate your help, I will continue with this as a reference. My thanks to you!